# how to understand setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, settimeout

First comes to my test code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(1)
}, 1);
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(2)
}, 0);
```

In Chrome, it returns 1, 2. But in Firefox, it returns 2, 1.
It seems strange between different browser. And Node has V8 engine like Chrome, but the code
below runs different too between Node and Chrome.

```
var start = Date.now();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
}, 2000);
```

Run code in node:

```
@tinple ➜  normalTest  node timer.js
1015
2002
```

Run code in Chrome console:

```
var start = Date.now();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
}, 2000);
10
1000 VM67:5
3811 VM67:10
```

It really get me confused and I really want to figure out it. I know this function is
declared by the browser or node. It cant guarantee the exactly delay that we preset.
So how to understand it deeply?

Update:

I just know that setTimeout with short delay may behave strangely accoring to different 
browsers.

Comment: The behaviour depends on the platform and the hardware you use. Don't forget that calling `setTimeout` requires processor ticks as well.

Comment: I don't have a link handy, but I think the spec indicates that the minimum effective delay is 4ms so by specifying a shorter delay you may actually get a result as if both `setTimeout` calls had 4ms. (Which could explain the result in Chrome.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: [the spec has actually changed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout): now if it's not nested more than 5 levels the minimum limit is left up to the user agent.

Comment: Thanks @Qantas94Heavy. Yes, I just found that one. Also [MDN has a note about this issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).